# Update date using triggers in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have a table that has a contract and columns like starting_date and expiration_date. I need to create a TRIGGER that for a specific category(private) as soon as we are at the expiration date(aka if it expires today), update it by one year.

What I don't really understand is, how could I update the date if I need to do an Update to fire the TRIGGER.

Like if I understand TRIGGERS correctly, I need to execute an Update statement to fire my TRIGGER and let it do its job. But if that's correct then what do I update to fire it?

For the TRIGGER obviously if I do **old.expiration_date == current date** then I will know if it is going to expire today.

For example let's say that we have a contract with:

**starting_date**: 1998/02/01

**expiration_date**: 2021/06/24

And **current date**: 2021/06/24

So now I need to fire that TRIGGER and update this date but how?

Here is the **table**:

```
CREATE TABLE insurance_premiums (
    contract_code text NOT NULL,
    insurance_team text NOT NULL,
    starting_date date NOT NULL,
    expiration_date date NOT NULL,
    contract_cost float8 NOT NULL,
    vehicle_contract text NOT NULL,
    customer_contract text NOT NULL,
    driver_contract text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT insurance_premiums_pkey PRIMARY KEY (contract_code)
);
```

Here is an **INSERT INTO statement** for the above example dates:

```
INSERT INTO insurance_premiums (contract_code, insurance_team, starting_date, expiration_date, contract_cost, vehicle_contract, customer_contract, driver_contract) 
VALUES
('FX-30592', 'private', '1998-02-01', '2021-06-24', 3894.68, 'Cavalier', 'Nicoline Vaughn', 'Helen-elizabeth Galiero');
```

Here is also the **TRIGGER**:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_contract
    BEFORE UPDATE ON insurance_premiums
    FOR EACH statement 
    EXECUTE procedure new_date();
```

And the empty **function** for the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.new_date()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    BEGIN
        
        
    END;
$function$
;
```

Again the TRIGGER needs to automatically update the date but I don't understand how I "call" it and how it would work

Comment: It's not a trigger job. You need a job scheduler of a kind to run the intended update once a day. Alternatively create a view which will amend the date in question on the fly.

Comment: Also, you should not store money in a float variable. And insurance_team appears to be a candidate for a foreign key.

Comment: Ok thank you all for your answers! I'm a beginner with SQL and I'm still learning. How should I store money? I thought that as a float would fit if its double precision. Also I will test Triggers with something different, I'm learning about Triggers now so I wanted to test them with something. But it seems this is not a triggers job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a trigger to have an action triggered by time. Triggers can only be fired on *data modifications*, that is `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `TRUNCATE` statements. That is not what you need here.

You would have to schedule a regular job that expires old entries by running a `DELETE` statement. Such a job can either be scheduled with operating system tools (like `cron` on Unix systems) or by a (non-standard) database extension like `pg_timetable`.

That will work if it is OK to expire data once a day or so. If you need more accuracy, I suggest that you modify your `SELECT` statements so that they ignore expired data. Then there is no rush expiring them.

If you have a coarser granularity (day/week/month) for data expiry, range partitioning might be the best option. That would allow you to simply drop a partition rather than running a long `DELETE`.

Comment: Thank you for your in depth detailed explanation of the problem  and possible solutions!